# Python PyMuPDF / Fitz rotates image from extractImage

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I am pulling out embedded images from pdf pages using PyMuPDF / Fitz. This works great but some pdf files, but for certain ones the image is rotated 90 deg. I don't see any condition that could be used to correct this. Has anyone experienced this? Anyone have a solution?

I always appreciate the help!

```
for img in doc.getPageImageList(i):
    xref = img[0]
    pix = doc.extractImage(xref)
    self.imagefilename = ("p%s-%s." % (i, xref)) + pix["ext"]
    imgout = open(self.imagefilename, 'wb')
    imgout.write(pix["image"])
    imgout.close()
```

Comment: I found this issue https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/335  The issue is closed but doesn't seem to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Message from the repo maintainer:

For the most recent PyMuPDF versions (v1.17.0 and up), I have decided to use the **unrotated page** for everything that can be inserted or modified.
Also every information about object location on a page now pertains to the unrotated page.
In addition there are complementary tools which allow transformations between the respective coordinate systems.

BTW: there is a PyMuPDF attribute `Page.rotation` which returns the page rotation. And you can set it via `Page.setRotation(90)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39324037/8222757

Using PyPDF2:

```
pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('example.pdf', 'rb'))
orientation = pdf.getPage(pagenumber).get('/Rotate')
```

The possible results can be `0`, `90`, `180`, `270` or `None`