# Extract Text from Rotated PDF by python

Tags: python, pdf, nlp, pypdf, pdfminer

I want to detect the angle of rotation and extract text from the rotated pdf.
tried using PyPDF2 but it is not able to detect the rotation.
I dont want to convert pdf to image for this purpose.
Please help.
[image: I have added image of sample pdf for reference]

Comment: This probably already has an answer here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515674/how-to-detect-a-rotated-page-in-a-pdf-document-in-python). You need to use the `/Rotate` attribute.

Comment: tried that, but to no avail. Doesnt work on the type of pdfs, I uploaded above

Comment: please add the problem pdf not image.